# Find the isomorphic ring and its order with $\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] / \langle 3x^2 + 5x \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is my attempt

this question realated with [Product of the ideal and normal groups(Is this solution right?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505845/product-of-the-ideal-and-normal-groupsis-this-solution-right?noredirect=1#comment7210665_3505845)

$sol)$ the solution is similar in the above link.

Let $f(x) = 3x^2 + 5x$ and $[f]_n$ be $f(x)(mod n)$

Then  $\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] / \langle 3x^2 + 5x \rangle $ =  $\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] / \langle [f]_{15} \rangle $ for $\langle [f]_{15}(= 3x^2 + 5x)  \rangle \lhd\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x]$

Here , $\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] \simeq \mathbb{Z_{3}}[x] \times \mathbb{Z_{5}}[x]$

Plus By C.R.T,  $\langle [f]_{15} \rangle \simeq \langle ([f]_3, [f]_5) \rangle  \lhd \mathbb{Z_{3}}[x] \times \mathbb{Z_{5}}[x] $

By the way, Since $\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] (\simeq \mathbb{Z_{3}}[x] \times \mathbb{Z_{5}}[x])$ is a ring with unity, $\langle ([f]_3, [f]_5) \rangle = \langle [f]_3 \rangle  \times \langle [f]_5) \rangle$

I.e. $\langle [f]_{15} \rangle \simeq \langle ([f]_3, [f]_5) \rangle = \langle [f]_3 \rangle  \times \langle [f]_5) \rangle$

So, ($\mathbb{Z_{3}}[x] \times \mathbb{Z_{5}}[x]$) / $\langle ([f]_3, [f]_5) \rangle $ $\simeq$  $(\mathbb{Z_{3}}[x] / \langle [f]_3 \rangle) \times $$(\mathbb{Z_{5}}[x] / \langle [f]_5 \rangle $)

But I'm not able to say the point "$\color{red}\simeq$" in the above link that first statement is not always true.

$\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] / \langle [f]_{15} \rangle $ $\color{red}\simeq$  ($\mathbb{Z_{3}}[x]$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_{5}}[x]$)/$\langle [f]_3, [f]_5  \rangle$ $\simeq$  $(\mathbb{Z_{3}}[x] / \langle [f]_3 \rangle) \times 
$$(\mathbb{Z_{5}}[x] / \langle [f]_5 \rangle $)

What should I next? or Are there any different ways without my method?

One thing sure is the order of quotient ring is 75

please help

Comment: Can you show that both $9x^2$ and $10x$ are in the ideal generated by $f$?

Comment: Same as OP's [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3504702/242) but restricted to this proof method,

Comment: @BillDubuque, To use restricted method, we must discover the element of the product satisfying the C.R.T.. But Finding it and showing the C.R.T is little complicated.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I added an answer explaining it. I thought Chris was going to do so after undeleting his answer to said prior question, but he never did. Perhaps I will update my answer there too to include this simpler way.

Comment: Haha :) Thanks for your more simple and kind explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $ $ in $\,R = \Bbb Z/15\!:\   (3)+(5)=(1)\,\Rightarrow\, (3)\cap (5) = (3)(5) = (0)$ $\smash{\overset{\small\rm CRT}\Rightarrow}\, R^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\! \cong R/3\times R/5$

The above ideal equalities extend to $\,E = R[x]/(3x^3+5x)\,$ thus also $\smash{\overset{\small\rm CRT}\Rightarrow}\, E^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\! \cong E/3\times E/5$

Ring isomorphism theorems $\Rightarrow E/3  \cong \Bbb Z_3[x]/5x,\,$ $\,E/5  \cong \Bbb Z_5[x]/3x^2$