# Is it true for finding the order of $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]/ \langle f(x) \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This question long-time bothering me.

Let  $f(x) = 2x^2 + 5x+1$

Find the order of $\mathbb{Z_{10}}[x] / \langle 2x^2 + 5x +1 \rangle $

---

My friends said it is not difficult. He suggested the solution like the below

$\mathbb{Z_{10}}[x] / \langle 2x^2 + 5x +1 \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z_{2}}[x] / \langle 2x^2 + 5x +1 \rangle \times \mathbb{Z_{5}}[x] / \langle 2x^2 + 5x +1 
\rangle  $

**Question)** Is it really true? then why? I'm doubt about his solution. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**p.s.)** Why having  I the doubt for his solution.

The link I asked)[Find the isomorphic ring and its order with $\mathbb{Z_{15}}[x] / \langle 3x^2 + 5x \rangle $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505942/find-the-isomorphic-ring-and-its-order-with-mathbbz-15x-langle-3x2?noredirect=1#comment7210805_3505942)

The link2 I asked)
[Product of the ideal and normal groups(Is this solution right?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505845/product-of-the-ideal-and-normal-groupsis-this-solution-right?noredirect=1#comment7210665_3505845)

Comment: If you have doubt's about the prior answers then you should ask questions in comments on these answers *before* posting more duplicate questions. You now have a handful of dupe questions that should have been only one question, and it is still not clear what specifically you have doubts about.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for your advice. I just wanna checking my friend's solution is right or not.(Accepting your thanksful  advice, I revised my question. )

Comment: Please don't significantly change the question after it's been answered (and dupe-closed). This can leave things in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a unital commutative ring and $ab=0\in R,au+bv=1\in R$ then $$R\cong R/(b)\times R/(a)$$
through $$t \to (t\bmod (b),t\bmod (a)), \qquad (x\bmod (b),y\bmod (a))\to xau+ybv$$
Here $a=2,b=5$

Comment: Is $R = \mathbb{Z_{10}}$ ? I can't understand what your answer  means. Does it mean my friend's solution is incorrect? Would you please explain solution more concretely?

Comment: $R=Z_{10}[x]/(2x^2+5x+1)$. Your question is "Is it really true? then why? I'm doubt about his solution" I explained why it is true and why it is the solution (of course you need to know how to find the number of elements in $Z_p[x]/(f(x))$)

Comment: To define the ideals of $R$ which is  $(a)$ and $(b)$, then does the "$a$" have to be $(2) / (2x^2 + 5x +1)$ not  2? (So does the "$b = (5)/(2x^2 + 5x+1)$")

Comment: $2=1_R+1_R$ is an element $R$. Of course $R/(2)= \Bbb{Z}_{10}/(2)[x]/(2x^2+5x+1)=\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(2x^2+5x+1)=\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(x+1)$ is the field with $2$ elements. $R/(5)= \Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(2x^2+5x+1)=\Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(3(2x^2+5x+1))=\Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$ has $25$ elements (since $x^2-2\bmod 5$ is irreducible it is the field with $25$ elements). Thus $R=R/(2)\times R/(5)$ has $50$ elements. It is a product of two fields thus its only proper ideals are maximal : $(1\times 0)$ (which corresponds to $(5)$) and $ (0\times 1)$ (corresponding to $(2)$)